# how to integrate phpbb and magento login and registration

Tags: php, authentication, integration, magento-1.9, phpbb

I want to integrate phpbb 3.1 and magento 1.9 by creating a log in form in magento that will serve as the log in/register form for both. the extension will have to accomodate just these three points.

1. A customer is logged-in and logged-out from both Magento and phpbb
   accounts simultaneously;
2. replace phpbb's complicated registration process with simple
   registration from Magento front-end;
3. Enables Customers to create a forum account that would be
   associated with their Magento account, yet configured separately.

What would be the best way to accomplish this with php? Does anyone have any Ideas?

If I complete the extension I will be offering it for free to the public.

Comment: This site is about problems in your code. Do you already have some code?

Comment: yes i tried inserting rows in to both magento and phpbb tables ..whereby an sql query would return true ... however this seems prity inefficient ... however I have noted your remark.Thanks for the reply

Comment: then show your query and tables, then people can tell if you do it the right way or give you improvements for your code

Answer (score 0):

there is a module for magento that does what you need
http://magesmart.it/phpbb-magento-integration.html